# AJAX Call to Controller from Partial View

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a Login page which is a partial view, and want to display database connection status when page is shown.

My idea is calling a database testing function in controller through AJAX, which returns the status string. But the controller function is not being fired, and the "success" function just get a HTML as response.

After hours of research but no success.

Could you please help. Thanks!

The controller returns login page:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

The AJAX call in Login page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(testConn, 100);
});

function testConn() {
    $('#msg').text('Connecting database...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("TestDbConn", "Utils")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (s) {
            $('#msg').text(s); // s is HTML, not a string what I want
        }
    });
}
```

The TestDbConn function in `UtilsController`:

```
public JsonResult TestDbConn()
{
    string result = "";

    try
    {
        var user = db.UserGroup.FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            result = "No available data!";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Database connected!";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = $"Unable to connect：{ex.Message}";
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Can you show msg controls too, pls?

Comment: Did you mean #msg? It's a html div element with id="msg". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It's nothing to do with the PartialView.
Just removes this from authorization section in the Web.Config.

```
<deny users="?" />
```

This line prevents users from accessing the Utils controller when not signed in, and `[AllowAnonymous]` tag does not help!